# Is it posible to animate color change without using color property in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML component containing an Image{} object that has no "color: " property set, and the color is instead passed to "svg from string" function from a string type property, and is later used as the svg image's "fill" parameter. It looks like this:

```
property string color: "aliceblue"
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to animate the color change using ColorAnimation QML Type, because it targets the "color: " property of the object, and it's not used at all in my case. The format of the color doesn't matter as long as it's supported by XML. (could be #RRGGBBAA etc)

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ColorAnimation` can be applied to any property, not necessary a color, for example, we can see the `ColorAnimation` being used on a `text` property:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        ColorAnimation on text {
            id: animation
            from: "red"
            to: "yellow"
            duration: 1000
        }
        onClicked: animation.restart()
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAABG3icVU8xDsIwDNzziqgTLFVZs0EnNvqEqDUQkdqV6wgQ6t9xoaqakwef73yWQz8Qi22kSaF9mJDRsiYUpjiai7+B/RirOCURwoXM8NjeiceyBRTgMzo7eNZ+NdQUiY8Yei9BN7UEXrJJmBE6p0mLJ1OuTL2zBUNXZHMhnb4hRnrmQpf4l+LsoaqqVZrWjrCO+h5sT5YMo3iW3d78zdMXm4pPNQ==)

In terms of recoloring an SVG, I always leverage from the `icon` property that can be found on many components, such as `Button`. The `icon` property has  `source`, `color`, `width` and `height`. In the following example, we use `icon.color` to recolor a space invader:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    IconButton {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: 256
        icon.source: "space-invader.svg"
        ColorAnimation on icon.color {
            id: animation
            from: "red"
            to: "yellow"
            duration: 1000
        }
        onClicked: animation.restart()
    }
}

// IconButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Item {
    id: iconButton
    width: height
    height: 64
    clip: true
    property alias icon: btn.icon
    property alias background: btn.background
    signal clicked()
    Button {
        id: btn
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        background: Item { }
        icon.width: parent.width
        icon.height: parent.height
        onClicked: iconButton.clicked()
    }
}

// space-invader.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<rect x="4" y="4" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="10" y="4" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="5" y="5" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="9" y="5" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="4" y="6" width="7" height="1"/>
<rect x="3" y="7" width="2" height="1"/>
<rect x="6" y="7" width="3" height="1"/>
<rect x="10" y="7" width="2" height="1"/>
<rect x="2" y="8" width="11" height="1"/>
<rect x="2" y="9" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="4" y="9" width="7" height="1"/>
<rect x="12" y="9" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="2" y="10" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="4" y="10" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="10" y="10" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="12" y="10" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="5" y="11" width="2" height="1"/>
<rect x="8" y="11" width="2" height="1"/>
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Another way to recolor an SVG, is through the use of data URI `image:data/svg+xml,` + svg_string so that you can generate a svg string on the fly, however, the way how this compiles causes flicker when used with `ColorAnimation`. In the following example we `ColorAnimation` on the `color col` property, but, we promptly type convert it to a string with `col + ""` when passing it to our `getSvg()` function. We make use of ES6 string interpolation to quickly embed this color into our target string.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Image {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        property color col: "red"
        width: 256
        height: 256
        sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)
        source: `data:image/svg+xml,` + getSvg(col + '')
        ColorAnimation on col {
            from: "red"
            to: "yellow"
            duration: 10000
        }
    }

    function getSvg(col) {
        return `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<rect x="4" y="4" width="1" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="10" y="4" width="1" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="5" y="5" width="1" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="9" y="5" width="1" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="4" y="6" width="7" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="3" y="7" width="2" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="6" y="7" width="3" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="10" y="7" width="2" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="2" y="8" width="11" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="2" y="9" width="1" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="4" y="9" width="7" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="12" y="9" width="1" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="2" y="10" width="1" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="4" y="10" width="1" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="10" y="10" width="1" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="12" y="10" width="1" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="5" y="11" width="2" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
<rect x="8" y="11" width="2" fill="${col}" height="1"/>
</svg>`
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)